# can't open file : [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

I get the following error when subprocess calls the process newtest.py. The code run as a daemon. When I started the daemon the process was called, it worked fine and did run 8 processes before started giving the error and then the error occurs at every call.
The error is

```
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'newtest.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

the code is below:

```
for index,row in enumerate(jobs):
            if index <= new_jobs :
                dirs=row[0]
                dirName=os.path.join(homeFolder,dirs)
                logFile=os.path.join(dirName,(dirs+".log"))
                proc=subprocess.Popen(["/opt/local/bin/python2.6","newtest.py",dirs],stdout=open(logFile,'a',0),stderr=open(logFile,'a',0))
                proId= proc.pid
```

I tried using the full path to newtest.py but it gives the same error.
Any suggestions? Many Thanks!

Comment: what is teh exact error message if you provide the full path ???

Comment: "file 'newtest.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" seems really, really clear.  What confuses you about this message?  The file doesn't exist.  What more do you need to know?  "tried using the full path to newtest.py"?  Please include the actual current working directory and this "full path" information.  Use `os.getcwd` to print the current working directory and `os.listdir` to **prove** that the file exists where you claim it does.

Comment: It is exactly the same with the path before the newtest.py

Comment: @S.Lott. But the file does exist in the current folder and the code did run intially, so I think that is not the problem.

Comment: @shash: "exactly the same with the path before the newtest.py".  This is neither code, nor evidence.  It's just a claim.  Please provide evidence.  Please print the values of `os.getcwd`, etc. to **prove** that the file really exists where you claim it's supposed to exist.

Comment: @shash: "But the file does exist in..." Then please prove it by including some output (along with the complete error message).

Comment: @S.Lott.It does work when I mention the full path before newtest.py. But I assumed that since the script is in the current directory my code should be able to run the script. It did initially worked without  mentioning the full path.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/opt/local/bin/python2.6','/FULL/PATH/TO/FILE/newtest.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Does that work? removed parameters and what not.

Also, can you do a:

```
f = open('/FULL/PATH/newtest.py')
print f
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if I've ever been affected by this on a Linux system, but here I am on MacOS with the same error.

I think I've solved it; you should change into the directory you are in in your forked process. I'm in something like `/Users/me/dev/project/` and running `bin/my-daemon start`.

In code, at the top of the daemonize method, I call `cwd = os.getcwd()` to a variable and then call `os.chdir(cwd)` in the fork.

It's been over half an hour and usually the daemon would have raised that `No such file or directory` error by now, but it hasn't.
This may not be an issue if your pid file is using an absolute path (`/var/run/my.pid`), but I'm using it relative to my project since I may not have write permissions and the user may specify where to write it.

**Edit**: Just realized how old this question was and the OP's code might reference a different issue. Here is the daemon code, slightly modified, that I was using:

https://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

I do hope this answer helps someone.